# extracting text from URL with $_GET

Tags: php, get

I have a URl that looks like this:

http://somedomain.com/article_view.php?articles=ViewAll

I am then trying to extract when articles=ViewAll using:

```
if(isset($_GET['articles']) && $_GET['articles']=='ViewAll'){
//do something here
}
```

It doesn't seem to be working as it never drops inside the if statement.  I assume my syntax is wrong but as a newbie I can't see my error.  Your help much appreciated.

Comment: What does 'I have...' mean? Is it the one of your site, or is it the one that you try to parse?

Comment: The if statement looks good. There must be a different error (in code you didn't showed here)

Comment: Are you sure you're using `ViewAll` as your value and not in any other case?

Comment: That looks right... now you need to test the code around it and make sure you're even getting to the IF statement...

Comment: 'it never drops inside the if statement' - are you sure you're getting to the if statement?

Comment: Remember string comparisons are case-sensitive, so you might be passing `articles=Viewall` or `articles=viewAll` instead of `articles=ViewAll` within the GET parameter.

Comment: Thanks guys.  You were right.  My code wasnt even getting as far as the IF statement.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me try it:

```
 if(isset($_GET['articles']) && ($_GET['articles']=="ViewAll"))
            {

            }
```

try checking the rest of your code or paste the rest of the code here so I can see what may be wrong

Comment: This is not an answer. Barely a comment even